# How does Karma know where to look for functions in WebStorm?

Tags: javascript, webstorm, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I've been looking into this for a couple of days now, and I'm clearly missing something. I've searched through Google and tried to follow examples from egghead.io amongst many others. I've successfully installed karma into WebStorm 8.0.3, and I can run test tests such as `expect(true).toBe(true)` or `expect(false).toBe(true)` and get the results one would expect. However, when I try to test a `helloWorld()` function I receive an reference error that helloWorld is not defined.

How do I tell my test script where my script to be tested is?

My file structure:

```
    -scripts
    --helloWorld.js
    -test
    --spec.js
    karma.conf.js
```

karma.conf.js (out of the box generated by WebStorm):

```
// Karma configuration
// Generated on Tue Jun 10 2014 16:47:49 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)

    module.exports = function(config) {
config.set({

// base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
basePath: '',


// frameworks to use
// available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
frameworks: ['jasmine'],


// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'test/spec.js'
],


// list of files to exclude
exclude: [

],


// preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
// available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
preprocessors: {

},


// test results reporter to use
// possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
// available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
reporters: ['progress'],


// web server port
port: 9876,


// enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
colors: true,


// level of logging
// possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: false,


// start these browsers
// available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
browsers: ['Chrome'],


// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
singleRun: false
});
};
```

spec.js:

```
describe('heelo world', function(){
    it('should say hello', function(){
        expect(helloWorld()).toBe('hello world')
    })
})
```

helloWorld.js:

```
var helloWorld = function(){
    return 'hello world'
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load your helloworld.js in karma config:

```
files: [
            'test/spec.js',
            'scripts/helloWorld.js'
        ],
```

you currently load test only, so that helloWorld() is unknow to karma

Comment: That did the trick. I thought I had tried that, but I couldn't have. Thanks :)